# Get image height attribute and display it in a CSS transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I use this to display image height :

```
<script>
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
document.write(this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';</script>
```

And this to change transform css :

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transform = "translateY(-100px)";
/* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.WebkitTransform = "translateY(-100px)";
/* IE 9 */
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.msTransform = "translateY(-100px)";
}
</script>
```

I'd like to combine those script to do something like this :

```
<script>
var img = new Image();
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transform = "translateY(-((this.height)-10)px)";
/* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.WebkitTransform = "translateY(-((this.height)-10)px)px)";
/* IE 9 */
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.msTransform = "translateY(-((this.height)-10)px)";
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';}
</script>
```

I don't know javascript so i need some help. The  question is : is there a way to display image height as style transform value. I need (this.height) to be minus 10.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sutrah/83xpxyxw/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite this function:

```
<script>
var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('height', 10);
function myFunction() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    myDiv.style.transform = "translateY(-" + (this.height - 10) + "px)";
    myDiv.style.WebkitTransform = "translateY(-" + (this.height - 10) + "px)";
    myDiv.style.msTransform = "translateY(-" + (this.height - 10) + "px)";
    img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
}
</script>
```

Or, since your question is tagged with the jQuery tag you could write it like this if you're using jQuery:

```
<script>
var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('height', 10);
function myFunction() {
    // jQuery should take care of the vendor prefixing of translateY for you
    $('#myDIV').css('transform', 'translateY(-' + (img.height - 10) + 'px)');
    img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
}

$('button').click(myFunction);
</script>
```

Comment: I [forked your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmerino/tdrwddyy/1/) and updated it so it works now. I forgot a couple things. I'll update the answer.

Comment: would it be possible to make it works onmouseover over "myDIV" itself ?

Comment: Yep, you could change the click binding to a mouseover binding like $('#myDIV').bind('mouseover', myFunction);